# The json array is not formed correctly. Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, forms

I am dynamically adding / removing fields for product properties using jquery. Then the data is converted to json and sent to DB, I get the following json array:

`[{"key": "123"},{"value": "21321"}]`

But I want to get the next one:

`[{"key": "123","value": "21321"}]`

```
<input type="text" name="properties[][key]" class="form-control m-input ml-3" placeholder="Key" autocomplete="off">
<input type="text" name="properties[][value]" class="form-control m-input ml-3" placeholder="Value" autocomplete="off">
```

This is how the correct array is obtained. But here the number of fields is fixed, while mine is dynamic:

```
@for ($i=0; $i <= 4; $i++)
 <input type="text" name="properties[{{ $i }}][key]" class="form-control" value="{{ old('properties['.$i.'][key]') }}">
 <input type="text" name="properties[{{ $i }}][value]" class="form-control" value="{{ old('properties['.$i.'][value]') }}">
@endfor
```

I also want to display existing values ​​for editing. I do it like this:

```
@isset($product)
 @foreach($product->properties as $prod)
  <div class="input-group mb-3">
    <input type="text" name="properties[][key]" value="{{ $prod['key'] ?? '' }}" class="form-control m-input editinp-key" placeholder="Key" autocomplete="off">
    <input type="text" name="properties[][value]" value="{{ $prod['value'] ?? '' }}" class="form-control m-input ml-3 editinp-value" placeholder="Value" autocomplete="off">
  <div class="input-group-append ml-3">
    <button id="removeRow" type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Remove</button>
  </div>
 </div>
 @endforeach
@endisset
```

But for some reason, if, for example, all 2 properties, the output is always 2 times more. I suppose this is due to the incorrect formation of the json array?

Answer (score 1):

When you give an HTML element `name="properties[][key]"` you are creating a new element on the `properties` array, which is an array with key `key`. So when the next element is named `name="properties[][value]"` then you add another new element onto the properties array. It's the same in PHP as this code, where the `[]` creates a new array element:

```php
$properties[]["key"] = 123;
$properties[]["value"] = 21321;
```

To keep these values together, you can use a numbered array entry instead of creating a new one. Try this instead:

```html
@foreach($product->properties as $i=>$prod)
    <input type="text" name="properties[{{ $i }}][key]" class="form-control m-input ml-3" placeholder="Свойство" autocomplete="off">
    <input type="text" name="properties[{{ $i }}][value]" class="form-control m-input ml-3" placeholder="Значение" autocomplete="off">
@endforeach
```

Assuming `$product->properties` is numerically indexed, you'll use `$i` as a counter variable and should end up with the format you're looking for. This is like this PHP code, where the same array element gets the keys added to it.

```php
$i = 1;
$properties[$i]["key"] = 123;
$properties[$i]["value"] = 21321;
```